# What kind of training would a person have to go through to withstand a hive mind

Tags: magic, hive, mind

In my fantasy world, certain people have the chance to consume a certain essence that gives them magical abilities when consumed. This essence gives them the ability to insert a piece of their "spirit" into a dead body. This reanimates the body into the wielder's control. This can be done with multiple bodies at a time, and they become a kind of fantasy hive-mind.

However, this would understandably have many negative effects on the wielder mind, having multiple bodies to control is not what it is built for. Think multiple perspectives of sight, touch taste, etc.

So, how would one prepare themselves for such a task? Remeber that this is a fantasy medieval world, where the people we are talking about have the technology equivalent to that of Imperial China.

Comment: How does a hive mind interact with a human mind? Without knowing the details of this, we can't answer this question.

Comment: Are you actually describing a hive mind?  Aren't the reanimated bodies dead?  If so, their minds are not contributing to the whole and, therefore, there is no hive mind.  This sounds like multitasking on steroids to me.

Comment: Formatting tip (since it seems to be a constant in your questions): insert break lines to make the wall of text more appealing to the eye.

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple bodies is something you can't train for directly, but perhaps we can view this from a few different angles:

Multiple bodies would mean a lot of additional sensory experiences. Hearing everything twice (or even more often), feeling things, for example pain, with multiple bodies simultaneously and so on. Meaning the person would need to prepare for that by testing the stress limits of the human mind. Extremly loud noises, making yourself familiar with extraordinarily strong smells, all extreme experiences could prepare you for controlling multiple bodies. And, of course, pain. Imagine you'd step your toes with three bodies simultaneously... Oh, the cries...

Another thing to keep in mind is the general willpower and intellectual capacity of the user of such a hivemind. He'd have to possess amazing orgazinatorial talent in order to manage more than one body at the same time.

But aside from a central mind with a lot of willpower one might not need training at all, because with every body the hive would get the tools to operate it in form of the new bodies brain, simply put, the network would be self-sufficent, as the hardware (body) comes with matching software (brain).